# Ansible how to get equivalent of nested for-loop in playbook

Tags: ansible

I am writing an ansible-playbook and am trying to accomplish the following:

- there are the existing directories /home/user1 , /home/user2, ... , /home/user20
- in each of these directories I want to create subdirectories /foo1 , ... , /foo5

Now I COULD just make use of a `with_nested` loop, where I provide two lists with all the indices that I need, but that is just silly.
Instead, I would like to define two number-ranges or -sequences and the relevant task is then looped over using the value-pairs from their cartesian product.

Is that reasonably possible and if so how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `ansible-doc -t lookup sequence` and [Forcing lookups to return lists](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#forcing-lookups-to-return-lists-query-and-wantlist-true) e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Create /home/user{{ item.0 }}/foo{{ item.1 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ query('sequence', 'start=1 end=3') }}"
        - "{{ query('sequence', 'start=1 end=2') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: Create /home/user1/foo1
  msg: Create /home/user1/foo2
  msg: Create /home/user2/foo1
  msg: Create /home/user2/foo2
  msg: Create /home/user3/foo1
  msg: Create /home/user3/foo2
```

The parametrized task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Create /home/user{{ item.0 }}/foo{{ item.1 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ query('sequence', user_range) }}"
        - "{{ query('sequence', dir_range) }}"
      vars:
        user_start: 1
        user_end: 3
        user_range: "start={{ user_start }} end={{ user_end }}"
        dir_start: 1
        dir_end: 2
        dir_range: "start={{ dir_start }} end={{ dir_end }}"
```

Comment: Thank you, that was just what I needed.